# getting all declared signals of an entity

Tags: vhdl

I want to have an elegant way of adding a logic analyzer to an entity (chipscope for xilinx fpgas). Like described in [ug936](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2012_2/ug936-vivado-tutorial-programming-debugging.pdf) there is the possibility to add an attribute to a signal (can be seen on page 10). This tells Vivado to keep the signal names (more or less) so that I can add them to the logic analyzer core.
The described method has the drawback that I need to do this by hand for every signal I want to trace. Which makes this method very error prone.

Is there any possibility in vhdl to get all declared signals within an entity and to iterate over it and assign the attribute in a loop?

Comment: The entity name list for the attribute specification can be a comma separated list of entity designators, the reserved word **others** or the reserved word **all**. You'd want to apply the attribute specification with an entity name list with **all** after the declarations in each declarative region. The attribute declaration (`attribute mark_debug : string;`) needs to be visible where the attribute specification is made (`attribute mark_debug of all : signal is "true";`). See IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.2 Attribute specification and 6.7 Attribute declarations. This works in earlier revisions.

Comment: Using  reserved words **all** and **others** here was supported in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL synthesis) but not 1076.6-1999.

Comment: The problem of using the keep attribute and such, is the you get a different implementation than without. The signals would otherwise be optimized away, which would lead to another structure. As a result, there is a chance that the implementation will also behave differently. I.e. timing/delay paths will be different, so possible clock domain glitches and such will occur at different places, or worst-case disappear. So watch out with these kind of synthesis/PAR attributes.

Comment: I know about these effects. I don't want to enable it all the time. What I want in the end is add a generic, where I can enable/disable this on purpose. So let's assume I implement a new module/entity and simulation works fine. But there is the chance that I missed something and the surrounding fpga is not behaving like I assumed. So my plan is to add this lines to new modules and activate it for integration and disable it after that. Timing paths and cdcs should be of little concern as they should be handled by different measures in the code. Of course this influences the netlist's behaviour.

Comment: The target of an attribute specification is an expression (e.g. "TRUE" or "FALSE", a string for attribute `mark_debug`. You could use a generic constant of type string to pass either possible values (default "FALSE") during elaboration of attribute specifications.